# Не удается совершить запрос

Tags: sql, access

Не удается совершить запрос. Ругается на отсутвие необходимого оператора в WHERE после "Заказчики.ДатаПриобретения"

```
SELECT Продавцы.Наименование, Заказчики.Наименование
FROM Заказчики, Продавцы, Заказы
WHERE Заказчики.ДатаПриобретения date BETWEEN    #10.03.2020# AND  #30.04.2020# ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас в запросе в 1 условии проверки даты указаны две величины для сравнения с диапазоном дат **Заказчики.ДатаПриобретения**  и   ***date***

Думаю, должно быть:

```
WHERE Заказчики.ДатаПриобретения BETWEEN    #10.03.2020# AND  #30.04.2020#
```

Или, маловероятно, так:

```
WHERE Заказчики.date BETWEEN    #10.03.2020# AND  #30.04.2020# ;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]